# list[-1] reports index out of range error

Tags: python-2.7, list, numpy, indexoutofrangeexception

I want to get the last element of a list. I use list[-1] but it reports index out of range. The step of the function is for each i in range(0,days), first to calculate tr, then let N = mean tr. Compare current N with previous N, if current N>1.5 previous N, then generate signal 1, otherwise, generate signal 0. How can I solve this problem?

Here's the code:

```
def cal_N():

    if days <= number_days: 
        lst = []
        for i in range(0,days): #cal tr
            h_l = sh600004['high'][i]-sh600004['low'][i]
            h_p = sh600004['high'][i]-sh600004['close'][i-1]
            p_l = sh600004['close'][i-1]-sh600004['high']
            tr = np.max(h_l,h_p,p_l)
            lst.append(tr) #append tr
        #calculate current N
            current_N = np.mean(np.array(lst))
            #signals['sys1 add'][date] = np.where( current_N > (N[-1]*0.5), 1.0, 0.0)
            if current_N>(N[-1]*0.5):
                positions['sh600004'] = 100 * signals['system1'] + 100*signals['system1'][i]
                print(positions)
            else:
                positions['sh600004'] = 100 * signals['system1']
                print(positions)
            N.append(current_N)
    else: 
            h_l = sh600004['high'][0]-sh600004['low'][0]
            h_p = sh600004['high'][0]-sh600004['close'][0]
            p_l = sh600004['close'][0]-sh600004['low'][0]
        # Calculate the True Range
            tr = max(h_l, h_p, p_l)
            current_N = (tr + (number_days -1)*(N))/number_days
            #signals['sys1 add'][date] = np.where( current_N > (N[-1]*0.5), 1.0, 0.0)
            if current_N>(N[-1]*0.5):
                positions['sh600004'] =   100 * signals['system1'] + 100*signals['system1'][i]
                print(positions)
            else:
                positions['sh600004'] = 100 * signals['system1'] 
                print(positions)
            N.append(current_N)
```

Comment: Try making your example smaller.  It seems like most of this code is irrelevant to the question, and this will not run in a self-contained environment (where is `N` defined, for example)

Comment: If `lst[-1]` causes an `IndexError` then the list is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
In [1143]: [][-1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1143-aeb23779f804> in <module>()
----> 1 [][-1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't see where `N` is initialized.  But if it starts as `[]`, then this test will have problems: `current_N>(N[-1]*0.5)`.  Even if the index worked, the result would be empty, and the comparison would not work, that `current_N > []` and `[]*.5` both raise errors.  So you have several reasons to test for, or prevent this action when `N` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens when you enter the loop the first time. At that point, N is an empty list. It could be fixed by adding a check whether the list is empty or you could give a default value for N.

By the way, calculate time series data for stocks (true range or other analysis), I will suggest you to try pandas. It will save loops and support array/matrix operations. Efficiency will be higher as well.

As you are analyzing SH stocks, even JQK might help you to have faster analysis.